# Does Gas constant depend on molecular weight?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, definition, ideal-gas, gas

I came across the following question recently

> Calculate the difference between two specific heat of 1 g of helium gas at NTP. Molecular weight of helium = 4 and J = $4.186×10^7$ erg $cal^{-1}$

The solution given is

[image]

If R is called the “Universal” Gas constant why does it change for different molecular masses?

I found this [website](https://www.ecourses.ou.edu/cgi-bin/ebook.cgi?doc=&topic=fl&chap_sec=01.2&page=theory) which talked about Gas constant vs. universal gas constant, but all the problems I’ve come across I’ve always used PV=nRT and haven’t had to consider the molecular weight. Why is this situation any different?

Could you please point out where I’m making a mistake or having a misconception on this topic?

Answer (score 1):

> but all the problems I’ve come across I’ve always used PV=nRT and
> haven’t had to consider the molecular weight. Why is this situation
> any different?

Because $R$ in the equation $PV=nRT$ is the universal gas constant, sometimes designated with an overhead bar as $\bar R$, is a single value that can be applied any ideal gas when the amount of the gas is given in moles ($n$).

On the other hand, for the equation

$$PV=mR_{g}T$$

where $m$ is the mass of the gas, $R_{g}$ is the specific gas constant. Since the number of moles of gas equals its mass divided by its molecular weight, the relationship between $\bar R$ and $R_g$ is

$$R_{g}=\frac{\bar R}{mol.wt}$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just for clarification, “where m is the mass of the gas”, in the equation m is the mass? Not molecular weight?

Comment: @Natru Correct.  $m$ is the mass, not the Molecular Weight.

Comment: So, nR = mR_g like my downvoted answer ;)

Comment: @buddhabrot yes. Have no idea why your answer was downvoted

Answer (score -1):

$nR_{universal} = mR_{specific}$, so if you deal with amount of molecules you can use the universal gas constant in the ideal gas law.

Comment: Not sure why anyone downvoted this